# How to disable a button which has two forms. When one form is valid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have two forms which share one button for submitting. those forms are in two different tabs. I want to enable the button only when the respective form in the tab is valid. Now my problem is when one form is valid the button on the other tab is also enabled. How do I disable a button when we have two forms?

```
<form id="form1">
<input type="text" value="test" name="test1">
</form>
<form id="form2">
<input type="text" value="test" name="test2">
</form>
<input type="button">
```

These forms are in different tabs. I want the button to enable only when the form1 is valid. And the button should be in valid when on the other tab. How do i acheive that?

Comment: what do you mean by form is valid?

Comment: Why aren't you creating 2 buttons? If you want to use one button only then you will have to bind an event to tab switching. When user is on tab 1 keep and form 1 is valid keep the button active, when user moves to tab 2 disable the button.

Comment: @Sourav, have you checked all these answers posted?

Answer (score 1):

To disable a button:

```
document.getElementById("YourButtonID").disabled = true;
```

To enable a button:

```
document.getElementById("YourButtonID").disabled = false;
```

I didn't get the full question ( probably because i'm dutch ) but that how you disable a button :)

Answer (score 0):

You can store the result of your form validation function (if you are using jquery validator or bootstrap form validation) into a variable and based on it, you can enable or disabled the submit button.

However you have not shared any validation code here so I can give you a brief code to guide you in a proper direction, I hope you will get idea from it.

```
var form_valid1 = $('#form1').validate({
                     // Here you will have your validation rules...
                 });
```

So if the form will be valid, then it will return true to your variable `form_valid` and based on it, you can put jquery code to enable or disable the button. (You can do the same for both forms with the same variable or with two different variables.)

```
if(form_valid != true)
{
    //$('input[type="button"]').attr('disabled',true); This is old anser.
    $('.tab').not($(this).find($(this).find('input[type="button"]')).attr('disabled',true);
}
```

Comment: I did this for my forms but as i said i have same button for two forms. So when one form is valid the button is enabled in both the tabs. I tried the validation for on tab change but its not working. I need a way to disable the button when not on the tab in which form is valid.

Comment: @Sourav, you can do this by excluding current tab's button to disable the other tab's button like this:  $('.tab').not($(this).find($(this).find('input[type="button"]')).attr('disabled',true);   I have updated my answer with this line too. I have assumed the tab div would have class `tab`. You need to set according to your html snippet.

Comment: When i click on disabled button its disabling the button in other form too .. What can i do for that..

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

You have to maintain two tabs in two different id with same classes. And also set  **data-attr = "tabid"**  And initially button should be disabled.Now your validation status passed means, just get the  **data-attr** from current tab id from current validation submit. Same classes may be used final submit.

```
var tab_id  = $("form_id").attr("data-attr");

$("#"+tab_id).find("button").removeAttr("disabled");
```